# Create Visual Studio Project for building using command

Tags: visual-studio, build, 7zip, sfx

I have a solution where there is a dependency on 7zip's sfx. Out of desire to keep the entire solution (plus the sfx) managed and coordinated, I want to create a new project to house all the source files that is used by sfx, and when building, execute a command line that tells 7zip to build a sfx from the source files, and place into the output so that it can be then referenced by actual Visual Studio projects within the same solution.

I think I can figure the command line by using Build events and providing the appropriate macros to ensure that the 7zip's output is placed into the target folder with appropriate name so that it can be then correctly referenced by other VS projects. But what I am not sure about is what Visual Studio project I need to use or steps to take to tell Visual Studio that there isn't going to be any code to be compiled in this project and it just has to execute this script I give it.

The closest thing I can come up with is VS's Make project but I don't know if that is the right thing since this has nothing to do with Make at all.

So, what is the Visual Studio project template I need to use? If empty, then what configuration do I need to perform so that it won't try and look for some code files to compile but instead just execute scripts as part of the solution's build?

Answer (score 0):

For now, it seems that using C++ Makefile Project works. I had to make few configurations:

1) I had to specify the project's "Configuration Type" as "Utility"
2) I used Pre-Build event and provided a command to invoke a batch file included in the project. The batch file then takes care of everything.
3) Normally, non C++ files are not considered for determining whether build is needed or if it's already up to date. To ensure that a new build is perform if the batch file or other key files are edited, I set the file's "File Type" to "MakeFile". Even though it isn't actually a Make file, it ensures that any edits made to the file will cause a new build.

The downsides I've found so far are:

1) C++ uses "Filters", not folders. Therefore, keeping the files in same directory structure is a big PITA. One can "include" files and get a one-to-one mapping between "Filters" and the actual directory structure on disk but it's annoying and tedious. Wish it was a C# project

2) I'm a bit wary about how it will detect new files or other changes for files that I didn't explicitly set to "MakeFile". I expect the source to be stable but I worry that when I realize I need a new file and add it, I might forget and not notice that the build is not correctly including the new file.

I'm not sure if this is the best method but this works for my purpose - having a project to manage external tools as part of bigger build process.